# Android studio automatically generating .png file during build time

Tags: android, kotlin, build, png, drawable

I have an Android app. Few months back I added a .png drawable inside it. Now I have removed it from the app and it's uses as well. I deleted all instances of it from the root folder.

The problem is the .png file keeps on generating after every build. When I analyze the .apk I could see that file. How can I remove it - from both debug and release builds? And why does Android Studio automatically generates them after eveytime?

If anyone could help me understand the logic behind this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried clear cache or Invalidate and restart?

Comment: Yes, did that. Even manually tried deleting the files from each (xxxhdpi, xxhdpi etc) folders and then invalidate cache, but they got generated again.